# CSS: centered text in div with min-height:100% overflows its borders

Tags: html, css

I've got a page with sections and the first section has got a min-height of 100% (html and body are also set to 100%) so that the first section always fills the whole viewport on page load. Since I've done this before it works so far.

Problem for me is that I want to place text inside this first section which is centered vertically and horizontally. This also works but here's the issue:

I decrease the browser's height -> the text is partially out of the viewport. It's alright. But when I scroll down then the second section already begins but the text overflows the second section and the first section does not extend its height according to the text belonging to it.

Sorry for my bad English I hope you understand what I mean.

I thought min-height means that the height of the first section changes according to the amount of text but everytime it just has the 100% viewport height and what doesn't fit into this space overlaps the section.

What could be wrong there?

```css
    #section-0-bg-image-red {
    width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /* background: some full page image with no-repeat center center fixed; 
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
     filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='...', sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='...', sizingMethod='scale')"; 
    */  
    background-color:red;
    } 

    #section-0-white-overlay {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8); 
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    }


    .outer {
        display: table;
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .middle {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .inner {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto; 
        max-width: 200px;
     padding-left: 20px;
     padding-right: 20px;
    }

    .headline {
        font-size:24px;
        text-align:center;
    }

    #section-1-yellow {
        background-color:yellow;
        width:100%;
        height:600px;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="section-0-bg-image-red">
     <div id="section-0-white-overlay">
      <div class="outer">
       <div class="middle">
        <div class="inner">
         <div class="headline">text to be centered horizontally and vertically but overlaps the first section when window height is decreased and user scrolls down
                        </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>  
     </div>
    </div>

    <div id="section-1-yellow"></div>
```

**UPDATE** with a jQuery solution:

Hey,

after spending some more hours on this I found out what prevented the first section from adapting to the text:

To center the text vertically the div with class "outer" had to be positioned absolute but this way the 100%-height-section had "no reason" to adapt to anything. Guess it's one of the CSS basics but what do I know? Too little. ;)

So I dismissed the CSS centering solution and decided to implement some kind of vertical centering for the text with jQuery by setting the padding-top of the text div depending on the window height:

```
$(window).on('load resize', function(){

var paddingHeight = ( $(window).height() / 3 ) - 80;


 $(".inner").css({"padding-top": paddingHeight + "px"});    

});
```

May be not very elegant but it does what it's supposed to.

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand, so please provide an image showing what you want it to look like.

Comment: Hey thanks for your response I added an image and hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what you're talking about. Rather than using `min-height` I think you should try setting the height to the full viewport like this:

```
height:100vh;
```

This will make whatever element that has that tag fill the entire viewport no matter what the viewport size is.

Here's a link to the JSfiddle. Let me know if that's what you had in mind.

https://jsfiddle.net/w4k6rzsy/1/

Comment: Thanks for your effort! No it's not what I mean (sorry) but your fiddle perfectly illustrates the issue: When you decrease the height of the result window until the text doesn't fit into the light red section anymore and you scroll down, then the text overlaps the yellow section. I'd like the whole text to be in the first section no matter how small the browser window is. The section's height shall adapt to the height of the text. I thought that is what min-height is supposed to do.